# Why does my dragonmapper installation fail with AttributeError for the 'hanzi' object?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use dragonmapper and I'm getting a confusing error. I installed it on Ubuntu 16.04 with the following command:

`pip install dragonmapper --user`

Then tried to use it:

```
import dragonmapper
dragonmapper.hanzi.is_simplified(u'你好')
```

but get the following error:
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hanzi'`

python --version outputs:
`Python 2.7.12`

What's up?

Also reported at https://github.com/tsroten/dragonmapper/issues/20

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I'm silly. I need to use `import dragonmapper.hanzi`.